# Eclipse comment text styling

Tags: eclipse, formatting, comments

I am looking to strike-through comments in eclipse but it seems impossible to do so. Is there a way to style comments in eclipse ?

I am not looking for ways to format comments.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary comments are just plain text and can't contain any styling.

A comment can contain a 'Task Tag' word (TODO, FIXME, ....). You can configure the styling of the Task Tag word in the Preferences.

Javadoc comments can contain Javadoc markup which will be interpreted when the comments are shown in the Eclipse Javadoc popup and the Javadoc view.